# Bad State: field does not exist within DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I am getting this error and it has something to do with my streambuilder here.  I have also tried doing `message.data()['text']` but that didnt seem to work either.

```
child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                      ),
                    );
                  } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    final messages = snapshot.data.docs;
                    List<Text> messageWidgets = [];

                    for (var message in messages) {
                      final messageText = message.data['text'];
                      final messageSender = message.data['sender'];

                      final messageWidget =
                          Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
                      messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
                    }
                    return Column(
                      children: messageWidgets,
                    );
                  }
                }),
```

[image]

Comment: `message.data()` is probably a method.

Comment: Yes, .data() is method, but upon research, people seem to be using .data['field'] regardless and it works. So I am wondering why mine will not. In this article: https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/04/04/using-cloud-firestore-in-flutter/ he uses this to retrieve as well

Comment: Show me where he is using it because everywhere I see he is writing `.data()` like here: `result.docs.forEach((result) {
      print(result.data());
    });`

Comment: Code won't let you know about that because you can pass this function/method to another function and invoke it there.

Comment: And if you don't invoke, you won't get data.

Comment: @Mises If you scroll down to the section named "Retrieve A Document", you should see it in the third code block. `print(value.data()!["address"]["city"]);`

Comment: And that's it, you copied it 2. `value.data()` this is how you can get data from DocumentSnapshoot. You need `()` becouse `.data()` is a method.

Comment: Yes but he's specifically was able to get into the address and city field even though he used .data() as well. I am trying to get into the 'text' field but I am getting that error

Comment: I don't see you are using `!` before `['text']`.

Comment: Same, I'm pretty sure `snapshot.hasData` is a method to, and you should use `()` there to. So you might not need to use ! But your `if()` is working all time even data not exists.

Comment: Using the ! did not work and adding `()` after hasData results in this error: `The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked`

Comment: If you still get error `Bad State:` it's probably because you invoke `.data()` where data not exits. In javascript you're checking are data exists with `snap.empty` and `snap.exists()`. Work on it, I'm not a flutter/dart programmer.

Comment: @Mises Solved. I guess its now updated and I should have used message.get('text') instead. Not sure how recent this change was or if its different my use case. I thank you for the help though!